# What should I do with a rude/abusive comment on an off topic question?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions, rude-or-abusive

I came across a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19306103) that had an obviously off topic question. Then I noticed that there was a comment right below it, clearly insulting the OP. There was even an upvote on it. I'm surprised that nobody had flagged it as rude/abusive.
[image]

My question is: does a comment underneath a poor question not count as rude/abusive? When should I flag a comment as rude/abusive?

Comment: Strangely the question itself was marked as "spam, rude, or abusive" despite being none of those things. Though obviously poor and completely unsuitable for SO. Wonder if the new moderator meant to mark the comment as such.

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to see this, the post was deleted.  How did this happen?

Comment: @HansPassant It was a review audit.

Comment: That *is* the kind of stuff you will run into when you review.  You inevitably see the worst of the worst.

Comment: I must have cleared the multiple flags on that post as helpful after deleting the question, not realising that one of them was a comment flag. Sorry for the oversight!

Comment: 

Comment: We are humans, so every of us have sometimes a minute or two of posting non-professional comments, occasionally "crossing the line". This may or may not be liked by others (bad humor), this is why it may get upvotes. Nevertheless such comments aren't welcomed by SO "be nice" credo and must be deleted. In given case I'd probably do both: upvote it and flag, because it will (fore sure) harm the person, but it's also funny considering the quality of question.

Comment: The best possible scenario would be that this person got *so* offended, he quit his job and never posted spam again.

Comment: @Xcoder You should edit the screenshot to censor the names of involved persons.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Comments count as rude if they are rude, that's it.

You should always flag rude and offensive comments, regardless of their context. We don't handle rude posts by posting rude comments.

Comment: Well in this case the whole post was deleted almost immediately after the comment was posted, so there's no real reason to delete the comment as the whole post was already dead and gone.  If the question weren't deleted yet, then sure, flag the comment.

Comment: @Servy The real reason to flag is that that user will probably post such comments again.

Comment: @SFTP Flagging doesn't do anything other than delete that comment though, so if that's your goal you aren't accomplishing it.

Comment: @Servy True, but I agree with SFTP. I just can't believe that comment got an upvote.

Comment: @Servy Unless the comment gets deleted automatically via several flags, a moderator will see the flag. And in any case, moderators see the history of user's comments flagged as rude. Stuff like that leads to suspension.

Comment: @Xcoder I don't find it especially strange that it got UV:d. Of course it's very rude and it should be removed, but I have to admit that my first reaction was to laugh. I would not have UV:d it myself, since it does obviously not belong on SO. But yes, I maybe have a weird sense of humor, and I'm also active on forums with WAY higher tolerance for rude behavior. The rules there are basically that anything goes as long as you stay on topic and do not make actual threats.