# Is anything spam anymore?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100491/how-to-implement-hdfc-payment-gateway-in-my-php-site/25932482#25932482) as spam

[image]

It's an ad for iPistis and (since that's not enough) doesn't disclose the [author's obvious affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444716/harish-kumar):

[image]

This flag was declined stating:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Is evidence looked for? If this isn't spam, or evidence of spam.... well what is now?

(Two other recent flags, on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448134/social-share-links-with-custom-icons/49542173#49542173) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548347/social-media-sharing-without-scripts/49582821#49582821), were disputed which I can sorta understand as you'd have to click offsite to notice that author's undisclosed [affiliation](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls/commits/master). But hey, at least what he's advertising is free.)

Comment: I was looking at other posts from this user, they were getting deleted while I was looking at them.  Appropriate lashings no doubt will be handed out for declining your flag.

Comment: By itself:  the post reads like spam.  In context:  the post looks like an answer to the question.  No doubt the moderator who declined it would be around shortly to defend their decision, but from this alone I could see "benefit of the doubt".

Comment: It's worth realizing that this answer was posted to a very bad question that *invited* spam like that *back in 2014*. Punishing a user for a 4-year-old post on a crappy question is almost entirely pointless. Just delete the question and call it good.

Comment: As animuson said, the root problem is the question, and dealing with that is the priority. Downvoting and deleting these answers would be fine, but it's excessive to throw spam penalties at an otherwise-fine contributor when the question doesn't invite valid answers in the first place.

Comment: It's really unintuitive that spam actually means "this *account* is spamming continuously in the last three months" rather than "this post is spam". It's also the first time I ever hear of a *question* inviting spam as some legitimizing factor of spam.

Comment: @animuson yes! exactly my point. Maybe you can write an answer.

Comment: @Felix It's not a legitimizing factor. But flagging the *answer* is the wrong move. Deleting the answer only doesn't solve the problem of a crappy question still being open and attracting more spam. Deleting the question takes out the spam with it. It's like editing a post but not fixing all of the errors in the post, just a few of them. We want to solve the entire problem, not just part of it.

Comment: @animuson exactly - which is why I  closed and deleted the source of the problem, the question.

Comment: Ok, I think I can start to refactor my thinking about this. I am still a bit uneasy about it, and wonder how, for instance if someone is working the review queues, we can hope that everyone always think to verify the question's context before flagging something as spam, but it's fair to go for the root cause. I'm not sure how to reconcile this with the somewhat widely spread idea that a post can be spam on its own.

Comment: While I understand why this answer might or might not be spam, I disagree with the apparent bottom line that "*since the asker asked for spam, posting spam is not spam*". That's what you diamonds seem to be saying but this doesn't sound like something you should want to be saying. At least I hope not.

Comment: @Felix If this had *just* been posted, I wouldn't have any objection to marking a spam flag helpful on it and taking out the question too. But this was posted four years ago, and hadn't been touched by any flags until a few hours ago. Going heavy-handed on it with a spam flag *now*, rather than simply destroying the question, is somewhat unreasonable. To be clear, these actions weren't the result of any review.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier it's common practice to check the question and the user account. Sometimes spam is obvious from the post : **Call now! Best removals!** Other times it may be programming related and even answer a question - so we need to see - does the question ask for recommendations? and so on

Comment: @YvetteColomb your point seems to be that the answer is not spam which you determined using your process you've been following. This is fine and is included in "I understand why this answer [...] might not be spam". My issue is with the rest of the diamonds in this thread trying to explain that because the question was crap and attracting spam, this somehow removes the burden from answerers to not post spam. That's a different issue and one that concerns me.

Comment: @Andras That's not remotely close to what we're saying. We're saying that you don't need to flag every single post under a crappy question, just as you don't need to flag every single obsolete comment under an answer. Flag the parent, explain it's all crap and it all needs nuked, and be done. Forcing hefty penalties onto someone by flagging individual answers isn't always necessary.

Comment: @animuson OK, I didn't mean to misrepresent your stance, but reading your first two comments in this thread came across in a way that gave rise to my interpretation. I'm glad if this is not the case.

Comment: It seems the penalty is playing a larger role than should be here. Is 100 rep a bit too much? If it were 50, would this discussion be different?

Comment: @Felix It's not just the reputation. Spam flags play into other systems that can full-out block a user from posting temporarily. For a post that they made 4 years ago, that would kinda suck.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah. I think I am starting to completely agree that if a user has spammed 4 years ago, forgotten about it, than lose more than all their reputation for it a while after the fact, that's very much not cool.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier exactly - I've updated my answer to try and help explain it more. The user appears to be active on the site and in good faith in the vast majority of posts. I wasn't going to penalise the user for something from 4 years ago and I wanted the flagger to know the flag wasn't helpful as a spam flag. Maybe I could add a custom decline reason.

Comment: Alright, fine, you can all keep flagging spam answers and pretending the problem doesn't lie at all with the questions. Don't let me catch any of you using the "off-site resource" close reason again.

Comment: @BoltClock If the suggested resource was something that the user was not associated with, then the post would not have been spam, because a resource was what the question was effectively requesting (and, obviously, the question should have been closed). However, because the user was associated with the resource they were recommending, they are *required* to disclose that association, or their post is classified as spam, regardless of the fact that resources were requested (and, obviously, the question should still have been closed). Yes, there are better solutions than spam flagging.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265628/when-is-spam-not-spam

Comment: @YvetteColomb Among the three criteria mentioned in the answer that you linked is, `[It is not spam when] an answer clearly discloses poster's affiliation with the product`.

Comment: Regarding the general defense of the decision stating that "*it is not spam because the question is asking for it*": [As discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365479/5894241) it is not acceptable to post rude comments/answers to rude questions, it shouldn't be acceptable to post spam answers to questions asking for spam.

Comment: @BoltClock I had voted to close the question as well. The entire argument that the clear problem was just the question is rather disingenuous when three other moderators on three prior occasions deleted three other answers without bothering with the question at all.

Comment: Man, I'd upvote this again if I could for this new title!

Comment: thanks to you I have this stupid tune in my head again. If I haddaway to get rid of it...

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't think deleting your answer was necessary. It explained your reasons why you considered the post not to be spam, and why spam-magnet questions should be handled first. And being wrong about handling the flags, or just making mistakes in general is not something terminally bad. Our best mods do that all the time. So I think your answer could've stayed along with your (not necessarily explicitly included) decision to feedback flags differently in the future.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well how about "This is the spam that never ends, they just keep posting it my friends, a user flagged for spaaaam not knowing what it was, so mods just keep declining it forever just because this is the spam that never ends, they just keep posting it my friends, a user flagged for spaaaam not knowing what it was, so mods just keep declining it forever just because this is the Spam that never ends..." [For tune click here](https://youtu.be/xz6OGVCdov8)

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeh, thanks for the ping. I've resolved it in my own head now and edited the answer and it's undeleted.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I'll only revert my downvote if you take the song out - ruined it :D LOL I really don't want to associate [this masterpiece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vc-PJPrueXY) with spam :D

Comment: @YvetteColomb Better?

Comment: Really enjoy the earworm meme here. Though I'm still worried about this years post-election meta fuss. Is this really about spam definitions and handling, not just precious flag scories again? The spammy answer got deleted "in time", didn't it?

Comment: @PaulCrovella yes much :)

Comment: @mario no, it's just that declined correct flags can be really annoying. And demotivating in the whole "keep the site clean" picture. I don't care for flag counts but I'm annoyed when flags are mishandled on purpose. Mistakes are different which is why mod explanations are crucial.

Comment: Nice question title :)

Comment: @animuson Considering you can get flag banned for declined flags you made years ago (if they get handled within 7 days & meet the other criteria), I don't think it's fair to give "old" spam the benefit of the doubt here. Yes, a 100-rep penalty's a bit harsher than getting flag-banned for a few days. But consider the options: 1) reject a valid flag and punish a user for doing the right thing, as well as send a confusing message on flagging, while letting a spammer off the hook because it's in the past, or 2) validate the flag and handle spam like spam, regardless of age. I'd pick #1 every time.

Comment: Thanks for not making me feel too old for recognizing this, and weirdness points. For you young ones, this is *Safety Dance* by Men Without Hats.

Comment: @Makyen, Paul Crovella: I'm making a point about Andras' argument that just because a question attracts spam answers somehow excuses posting spam answers. Which is *equally* disingenuous. Which is my point.

Comment: Sorry, but the memetic editing of the title started to *really* distract from the topic.

Comment: @Machavity If you want to change the title to something less confrontational that's fine, but please do so without changing the question asked.

Comment: Without changing the question asked? Tbh not really clear what that is with the title `We can flag if we want to, we can leave the spam behind. 'Cause this post is spam and if it is spam, well it - gets a flag of mine`

Comment: @MartinSmith That was a fun title indicating the topic, leaving the question to the body. The title I reverted asked a different question entirely.

Comment: I don't understand why the title had to be edited to begin with. I thought the original title was hilarious, and a perfect fit for the question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Was that answer spam? Yes, it certainly looks like it.

In a case like this, we have four options: apply a hard spam flag (immediately validating the flag and applying harsh penalties to the user), deleting the post (validating the flag, but not applying those penalties), clearing the flag (disputing it), or declining the flag.

For clear and recent spam from an account created only to spam, I typically choose the hard flag to prevent more from coming in. For older spam or spam left by accounts that have other contributions, I'll delete the post, validate the flag, and warn the account if they're still around.

I'll typically dispute spam flags in borderline cases where I can see what someone was flagging, but either disagree with the content being promotional in nature or think that the post would trip people up in audits. I may still delete the post, depending on the context, and clearing the flag doesn't penalize the flagger.

I decline flags where there is no evidence of self-promotion and I want to indicate that the flag was used incorrectly. We get a lot of that, because some people regard as "spam" things like repeated questions, bad questions, or answers they simply don't like.

In this case, I don't think a hard moderator spam flag would be appropriate, but deletion of the post and marking the flag as valid would probably be what I choose. Disputing the flag may also have been a possibility, but that answer would seem to be an clear case of spam if presented to someone in an audit without context.

Let me comment on the other two spam flags you mention (the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448134/social-share-links-with-custom-icons/49542173#49542173) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548347/social-media-sharing-without-scripts/49582821#49582821)). Those are a different case. A moderator had originally applied a hard spam flag to those in addition to your spam flags, leading to a 200-point reputation penalty and IP restrictions around that user. In response to other flags, I reviewed those and cleared (disputed) the flags to remove these penalties.

I did so because the link wasn't a commercial effort, it was a collaborative list of resources, and they were merely a contributor to this list. I'm a lot more forgiving when it comes to open-source GitHub projects, particularly when someone is a contributor and not a host of a repository. They were an otherwise good long-term member, and I didn't see this as an explicit attempt at self-promotion.

Comment: Thank you, Brad. I really did just want to know what to flag, as what happens from there is your business rather than mine, but the additional info is appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: The question seems to have been deleted, so I can't judge whether the flagged answer was a legitimate answer to the question or not, but now I'm feeling a bit self-conscious. I've occasionally posted answers [such as this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298537) that involved the use of my own tool—should I refrain from doing this in the future?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka there is a lot of guidance on [meta-tag:self-promotion] here, see in particular [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298734/839601) and [What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361313/839601)

Answer (score 65):

I will post my own answer because I firmly believe that the messages that moderators have posted on this question are wrong and they do not answer the question.

If we go by the definition of the help center, [Usage guide for spam and rude/abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035):

> A post should be marked as spam only if it **advertises** a product, service, or similar and **is unsolicited or lacks disclosure**.

Does the post...

- Advertise a product? Yes, it advertises paid support
- Is it solicited? Well, no, "if you are looking for paid support..." (who asked for paid support?)
- Does the author disclose the affiliation with the product? No, he doesn't

So, is it spam?

## Yes, the post is spam.

I really don't see how the fact that the spam was posted 4 years ago should free the user from the penalty. What prevents the user from posting spam again? Nothing, they got out with it for free.

If moderators won't follow the guidelines in the help center, they should either do not touch spam flags or edit the help center so that the "proper" way to flag is taught to normal users.

Comment: Note that the latter bit is an "or", not an "and". Even if the question had explicitly been "I am looking for paid support...", the lack of disclosure would be enough to call it spam anyway.

Comment: @NicHartley However, if there was disclosure it would not be considered spam because of the "and" between the first two conditions.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That's correct -- if the question is "I'm looking for paid support" and the answer was "My company provides paid support", that would be acceptable. (I mean, the question would be wildly off-topic for at least one reason, but the answer wouldn't be spam, at least)

Answer (score 19):

One aspect of this that I think is being ignored: we should moderate content, not users, here. Granted, this is a somewhat unusual case in that this is "old" spam, so there's less of a benefit to punishing the poster now if they haven't done it again since, but it's still spam.

In my opinion, the intent of the post (as well as how "blatant" the spam is) is a bigger factor than the user's other content. If a new user links to their blog without disclosing the affiliation, that's probably not malicious on their part, it probably just reflects them not knowing site rules - in that case, commenting explaining the policy should be adequate (possibly either editing or flagging as VLQ if appropriate). It would be a little harsh to apply the "hard" penalty in a case like this. In more blatant cases, though, the hard penalty should just be applied regardless of the user's other content.

I do recognize, of course, that sometimes even there there are probably exceptions. For example, as I mentioned above, there's probably less of a point to applying the hard penalty in a case like this with 4-year-old spam where the user hasn't spammed again since. Cases like this should be treated as the exception, though.

I'm somewhat concerned that, if some of the discussion on this is applied consistently, it would lead to moderating users rather than content. In fact, if we only flag spam from accounts that were created specifically to spam, that's kind of the definition of moderating users rather than content.

Apart from being contrary to the point of moderation here, this could lead to blatant unfairness as well as permitting bad behavior. Effectively, this could easily give certain users a "free pass" to spam as long as they're contributing legitimate content. Pretty soon, new users would (rightly) question why they're not allowed to spam too if they see high-rep users getting away with it.

In some ways, this reminds me of the classic question that's asked every moderator election: what would you do with a high-rep user that also generates a high volume of rude comments, heated debate, etc. Almost invariably, people say that having a high reputation doesn't exempt you from the "be nice" policy.

Point being: no amount of "good" content exempts you from site policy. In order to be effective, rules should be applied consistently and uniformly. Ultimately, spam is spam, and we should moderate content, not users. Also, if you don't want to get penalized for spam, don't post spam.

**TL;DR** Spam is spam regardless of who does it. The principle of moderating content rather than users - as well as basic fairness - dictates that we ought to apply the rules consistently and uniformly.

Comment: Nobody's saying that fresh spam from an otherwise-good user would be tolerated.  (It may have come out that way, but I don't think that's what anyone *meant* to say).  This is about a missed penalty 4 years ago, and the pointlessness of applying it now when the user has not been spamming recently (and hopefully isn't planning to / knows not to by now).  This is not a slippery slope.  It definitely should have been flagged as spam 4 years ago when first posted, and would have been nuked.  But it got missed.

Comment: @PeterCordes It has definitely been implied in some of the discussion surrounding this (comments, at least one now-deleted answer, etc.) that you need to look at posts in the context of the entire account to determine whether something's spam or not (including whether or not the user in question is generating legitimate content or whether the account was created primarily to create spam). At a minimum, that seems to come dangerously close to moderating users rather than content, which I think would be a very bad thing for the site. Moderation should *always* focus on the content itself.

Comment: Oh, yes I see Yvette's deleted answer, voted +17/-37 = -20.  So clearly the community already disagrees with that viewpoint (and our newly-elected moderator has learned something and will at most dispute similar flags on old posts in future, not decline them).  *This* answer would be better if you link to some of the specific things you're refuting, especially the deleted answer which justifies this one.

Comment: @PeterCordes The viewpoint does actually seem to be fairly common I think (some of the comments seem to imply something similar, and I've heard that idea brought up in chat before), which was one of the main reasons I wrote this - I strongly feel that we should focus on the content, even if the user is generating other legitimate content. While I agree that there's less of a point in this particular case sinced it's so old, in cases with "fresh," unambiguous spam I think that the moderators should just apply the hard penalty regardless of what other content the user has created.

Comment: Ok, yes I agree with spam = spam regardless of who posts it.  But for otherwise-good accounts, a message from a mod will probably be effective, unlike with an account created to spam.  So users should flag spam when they see it, and mods can decide on a course of action that will stop the spam from continuing.  i.e. Whether to apply an insta-ban with IP blocks (inappropriate for a first offense by a "good" user), or a warning, or something in between.

Comment: If you said something more like that, and accepted that disputing the spam flag made sense for old posts sometimes because of how the system works (not because mods don't actually consider it spam, as Brad explained), then I'd be happy to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 11):

This [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365691/is-anything-spam-anymore#comment571846_365691) by @animuson defuses my less positive emotions about all this quite efficiently:

> It's not just the reputation. Spam flags play into other systems that can full-out block a user from posting temporarily. For a post that they made 4 years ago, that would kinda suck.

It would indeed kinda suck, if someone spams four years ago, displays absolutely no other spamming behaviour, then loses more than all of their reputation a while after.

That could have been disputed as [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365691/is-anything-spam-anymore#comment571837_365694) by @Makyen, but I think that can be brushed off without too much pain.

Comment: If the site owners don't want to punish accounts for four year old spam behavior, the post date is really easy for the penalty logic to check.  The post is still a spam post and still deserves a spam flag.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's a great feature request! You should post it on [meta.se].