# Nothing is spam anymore

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam

This is a sad continuation to [We can flag if we want to, we can leave the spam behind. 'Cause this post is spam and if it is spam, well it - gets a flag of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365691/what-is-spam-baby-dont-flag-it-dont-flag-it-no-more)

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744219/bottomnavigationview-between-activities/49712094#49712094) as spam:

> in
>
> > BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
>
> or other methods that you wanna switch between activities add a delay
>   in loading new Activity .
>
> **lots of code here, which may or may not answer the question, I don't know Java
>
> our website (link)

I now see this in my history:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

BUT, wait, doesn't the help center [specifically says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035):

> If an **otherwise valid** post contains an apparent spam link, **flag as
>   spam**. Do not try to salvage the post by removing the spammy content.
>   The valid part of such spam posts is usually plagiarized from another
>   post or from an off-site source. If you're unsure, you can often find
>   the original source with a Google search of its first sentence.

The mod that refused the flag (I'd guess) then went and removed the link from the answer.

So, should I edit myself and don't care about the help center or should the mod had handled the flag differently?

Comment: In this case it's similar to the "signature" but contains a link? ...

Comment: Can we dial down the "cleverness" in titles here? Surely there are hundreds of spam flags being marked helpful every day, including today and tomorrow.

Comment: Mind linking to the post?  I'm assuming that there's some *hard* context in here that would be easily rationalized or explained if we could see the post in context.

Comment: @Makoto There's nothing to the post that I didn't quote, but link added

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto:  I happen to understand Java rather well and could tell if an answer in Java at least *looks* like it's an attempt at answering the question.  Adding the link definitely helped.

Comment: Coattail riding good times...

Comment: Quote: "Well, as a user, I surely won't take the time to google...".  If you don't want to take the time then just leave it to somebody else.  That includes the option to leave it to a moderator to sort out.  He did, nothing actually went wrong.  That he had to remind you that you did not take enough time, well, you already knew that :)

Comment: The help centre text you quote seems to have been added in in this revision. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGNMu.png. Is it official policy? I've no idea. The person that edited it in isn't a moderator.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have [pinged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#comment1006578_58035) the editor over there. (Between the lack of autocompletion for editor pings and the Unicode username, I hope the ping has actually happened...)

Answer (score 15):

In context, I would not see this as spam per se. I see this as at *least* an attempt to answer the question with an ill-advised self-promotion.

I would imagine that the flag would be useful to alert the moderator to give the person a stern talking-to and state that's not how we do self promotions here.  But everything else about the answer *might* be useful to someone else, so I don't see a reason to destroy it with a spam flag.

The difference between spam and a (likely) honest mistake:

- If it's *just* a product placement, then it's spam.
- If there's an attempt at an answer and then there's a strange link, then it's probably not spam.
- Assume good faith on the part of the answerer.

Comment: I find this a better answer, however, would you have agreed with a declined flag?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto:  Yes.  It's not spam so there's no reason to accept it.  It's not that it's wishy-washy either - it does read like there's at least *some* kind of attempt at an answer - so disputing it would send you the wrong signal.

Answer (score 6):

What you refer to as "help center" isn't that. It's a Meta post like yours. It's edited collaboratively, and it expresses the opinions of its authors.

Specifically, the guidance about flagging legitimate-looking posts as spam is motivated by the prevalence of copy-pasted text (from another site, or even from Stack Overflow itself) with a SEO-friendly link inserted and usually disguised.

"[Our website](https://example.com)" is not that, it's more like a signature than something one would put in for SEO purpose. I don't see any evidence of the text being plagiarized, either. You quoted

> you can often find the original source with a Google search of its first sentence.

... well, have you found it? I didn't.

I'm inclined to assume good faith on the part of the poster, who also posted two other answers without such a link.

Comment: Well, as a user, I surely won't take the time to google to find out from where the OP obtained that code. It could well be part of a project they have, how could I know? The help center links directly to that meta post, so I take it as part of it. I did look at the other two posts, but as was said in the other question I mentioned in my post, one should flag posts, not accounts

Answer (score 2):

I once asked this question over at Meta Stack Exchange: [How to deal with an otherwise salvageable post with a spam link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303698/350567)

I'm just putting ChrisF ♦'s response here verbatim, as the post you've faced is *exactly* "otherwise salvageable but with a spam link".

> If, at first glance, the the post looks good but has an apparent spam link at the end there's a good chance that **it is really spam**.
>
> The legitimate content will have been plagiarised from somewhere (possibly even another question/answer on the site) and simply copied and pasted with the spam link added. A quick search for the first sentence of the post should confirm this.
>
> Flag as spam.

**I vote for that the mod should mark the flag as helpful**, or at least "dslisputed", regardless of what other action they take.

There's one thing to note: While I would also flag it as spam for the reason pasted above, a quick Google search indicates that it's unlikely plagiarism. It's recommended that you check for plagiarism before flagging these kinds of answers as spam. The easiest way is to just look at other answers under the same question, and if yes, proceed to flagging.

Comment: So if it's not plagiarism it's not spam? I really don't get it. I guess I just won't use that flag again

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If it's not plagiarism, **hesitate** before flagging as spam.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The key part of the quote is "A quick search for the first sentence of the post should confirm this". In grey zone situations like this one, I'd say that, if you care about not having your flags declined, the burden of proof (or at least of reasonable evidence) is yours.

Comment: @iBug By the way, thank you for answering here. Taking into account what we are saying here, perhaps it would be worth it to tweak that Meta.SE paragraph to make it sound a little less absolute.